# Create an App ID for a page to connect Live stream to the page

Tags: facebook, web

I would like to connect my page on facebook to my website, using the livestream plugin ( http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/live-stream/ )

It asks for an app id. How do I create this for a facebook-page? I have tried everything (at least!) It is really not clear to me how to create this app id for my page to add in the livestream plugin.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/apps is where you create a new app - the app ID is displayed in your list of apps and in the App settings page.

Comment: Thanks, I have come so far, but I cant find out how to Set up the app correct. I can tell that my app id is 310151325680020, but when i type this on this site: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/live-stream/
It shows my profile. I want it to show the profile for my company..